# 404 Errors When Launching Proxied Plotly-Dash Application from Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, plotly-dash, nginx-ingress

As the title outlines, I'm having issues getting an application to run from a Jupiter lab environment. I'm not quite sure how to even begin looking for an answer... Maybe even a better explanation of what's happening when I run the server.

Dash is building and running the server, but it doesn't seem to be pulling the necessary packages from local. All of the needed dependencies and dash core components are spitting out 'file not found' errors, which means that the ways in which these dependencies are acquired from WITHIN jupyter lab are not working. If I had a magic argument that I could put into dash.Dash(), it would be "PULL_DASH_DEPENDENCIES_FROM_THIS_LOCAL_PATH" that would place them into the appropriate directory structure in the created server URL.

Any ideas on what's going on? Screenshots/code are below.

Inspect Element of Resulting Dash Application:
[image]

Relevant Dash Code:

```py
runurl = '/' + user + '/' + project + '/r/notebookSession/'+ runid + '/'

app = dash.Dash(__name__, routes_pathname_prefix='/', requests_pathname_prefix=runurl)

# Dash code (tested and runs locally)#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=8887, host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: I haven't tried something like this out before so I don't really know the answer, but this blog post looks relevant and promising https://lukesingham.com/how-to-deploy-plotlys-dash-using-shinyproxy/.